# How to use a lot of images in android's application

Tags: android, performance, android-image

I have a huge android application that use more than 400 images so my app it's late even I tried to optimise it. What are the best practices in this situation?

1. I  create the APK and the customer download all the images
2. Add some Images to application and the rest to download on the installation
3. Add all the images even the APK becomes more than 40Mo

Comment: use APK expansion, download images at first install or use image loader lib.

Comment: I use picasso for images, and I couldn't pass 40Mo for my company.

Comment: after install and then download all images its become 40mb????

Comment: no the apk's size 40 Mb

Comment: then use APK expansion, put all images in to that expansion, your APK size reduce up t0 10 mb. or download all images after install